# Does a Windows process need to be terminated by ExitProces() or TerminateProcess()?

Tags: windows, winapi, portable-executable, entry-point

I have this simple program:

```
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI startMeUp() {
  return 0;
}
```

which I compile using the command line tools of Visual Studio like so:

```
cl /nologo /GS- /Gs- /c /W4 main.c /Fomain.obj
link /nologo main.obj /subsystem:console /entry:startMeUp /nodefaultlib kernel32.lib user32.lib /OUT:the.exe
```

When I then execute `.\the.exe`, a message box is shown that says *the.exe has stopped working - A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available*

After replacing the `return 0;` with `ExitProcess(0);` and re-compiling/linking it, `.\the.exe` runs just fine.

So, it seems to me that `ExitProcess()` is needed to correctly end a process.

Since I am pretty sure that I already had working programs that returned from the entry-point function by returning an exit value, I am not sure if portable executables require a process to be terminated by `ExitProcess()`.

**Edit**
Interestingly, if I place a `MessageBox(NULL, "world", "hello", 0);` before the `return 0;` (and thus don't have an `ExitProcess()` call), the executable also runs ok.

**Edit II**
When I add the linker option `/export:startMeUp`, the linker warns me with `LNK4216` *but* I can execute the created without problem.

When I use `dumpbin /all` on both exes created, I see that the faulty executable has

```
 0 [       0] RVA [size] of Export Directory
```

while the new, working one has

```
2000 [      40] RVA [size] of Export Directory
```

Also, the working executable consists of two sections: `.text` and `.rdata` while the faulty one only has the `.text` section. The executable code seems to be included in the `.rdata` section, thus it is missing in the faulty one.

As to *why* that is, I have no clue.

Comment: Usually you don't provide /entry, and do provide a WinMain function. This starts up the c/c++ runtime which is going to be important for any non trivial application as its nice to have global initializers run, and floating point and exception support available.

Comment: Also, perhaps your signature is wrong. When ive done my own entry point in the past, the application simply closed when I returned in trivial apps, and did not when I didn't - if you don't call ExitProcess then the process won't close if there are any worker threads created, and lots of things expect to create worker threads.

Comment: Yeah, get rid of the custom entry point and let the runtime do the work for you

Comment: Lastly, `TerminateProcess` is useful for process to terminate another process that is not responding. You should avoid that use whenever possible as you can inadvertently terminate a process while its busy updating files and cause it to corrupt its data files.

Comment: If you want a more standard c-runtime environment even for gui apps, you can force msvc to always expect `main` by doing a /entry:mainCRTStartup and ensuring that a runtime is linked (i.e. drop the /nodefaultlib and/or explictly add msvcrt.lib)

Comment: hm.. your program must not crash. it can not exit (if additional threads will be created inside it), but exception must not be. or upload your finally *exe* for look it

Comment: Hmm. In NT 6.0+, threads start at `RtlUserThreadStart`, which gets passed the image entry point and the PPEB. But first an APC calls `LdrInitializeThunk` to initialize the process. kernel32.dll initializes the `Kernel32ThreadInitThunkFunction` function pointer to `BaseThreadInitThunk`, which gets called from `RtlUserThreadStart` with the image entry point and PPEB. This in turn calls the image entry point with the PPEB. The return value is passed to `RtlExitUserThread`. If it's the only thread, it calls `RtlExitUserProcess`, which in turn calls `LdrShutdownProcess` and `NtTerminateProcess`.

Comment: It should work fine. It works for me in Windows 10.

Comment: even with only single *.text* section your exe must not fault. however can you upload it for look ? visible also that you use old enough linker. the new will create by default pogo data in *.rdata* section. for prevent this - add `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO` for linker option. and not need export entry point

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the linker. The fact that it works if you include a trivial import... The actual exception stack trace would be interesting / informative.

Answer (score 1):

windows process exit or when last thread in process exit or when `TerminateProcess` called. because can be additional (implicitly created) threads in your process - you need call [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) (or [`ZwTerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-zwterminateprocess)) direct or indirect.

the [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) internally call `TerminateProcess` (ok really `ZwTerminateProcess`), but before this do some job, for correct process shutdown. including calling all DLLs entry points with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` notification

so in general you must call `ExitProcess` (more correct) or `TerminateProcess`

in case you write entrypoint yourself, the correct signature must be

```
int WINAPI startMeUp(void*)
```

this is *stdcall* function which take 1 param (pointer to *PEB*). when you return from this api to system - just `RtlExitUserThread` called, which cause to thread exit or all process exit if this is last thread in process. even desite on x86 system stack pointer is incorrect after your return from `startMeUp` this not lead to error because just `RtlExitUserThread` and it never return. hard say what lead to crash in your test without view your binary file, but faster need look(debug) on your concrete system. but this is unusual - this must not be. your process must or just exit or still live (infinite or some time) in background in additional thread in process exist

Comment: Note that before calling `LdrShutdownProcess`, `RtlExitUserProcess` (i.e. `ExitProcess`) first terminates all other threads in the process with a special `NtTerminateProcess` call using a `NULL` handle value. After the loader has shut down the process, it calls `NtTerminateProcess` a second time to really terminate the process.

Comment: @eryksun  - yes, you absolute correct, simply i not describe here in details how `RtlExitUserProcess` work

Comment: It's relevant to the fact that simply returning from the image entry point isn't a deterministic way to exit the process. It works in the OP's case since there's only one thread, but `RtlExitUserThread` won't call `RtlExitUserProcess` if it's not the last thread (as determined via `NtQueryInformationThread`). Thus, as you said in your answer, if we want to reliably exit in general, we have to call `ExitProcess` from the entry point instead of returning from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply ask if ExitProcess() is needed in exe i may answer yoo strictly: NO

I wrote a compiler that generetes exe and minimal program in it (if not saying about exe headers) may only have one byte: 0xC3 which is ret - such program when run return immediatelly but is correct

Comment: but in this case this *exe* can not terminate after `ret`

Comment: hell no, it behaves correctly just immediately ends..everything else is fine